# Nginx: mesh response - body static, header from proxy

Tags: nginx

How can be reponse from Nginx assembled in such a way that response body comes from static file and the header from upstream proxy?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using SSI. Your upstream should return body with [the `include` SSI command](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#commands).

```
<!--# include file="footer.html" -->
```